# Use WHERE clause only for one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT COUNT(dog.id) as dogs_count, SUM(dog.age) AS total_age WHERE dog.owner IS NULL;
```

I have a table dog and I need to return the sum of all dogs' age. A dog may have or may have not an owner. I need to return the count of all dogs without owners. So far so good - the WHERE clause returned all dogs without owners, but now I get the sum of all stray dogs and not the sum of all dogs in general. How can I use WHERE only for one row or maybe do it some other way ?

I have 2 dogs each one of them is 2 years old. One of the dogs has no owner.
The query should return 1 for dogs_count (because only one has no owner) and 4 for total_age because the dogs age combined is 4

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Also, why doesn't your query work?

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample

Comment: @GordonLinoff  the query works but not as intended. I need the sum of all dog's age, not just those without owner.

Comment: @Mureinik I will include sample data

Comment: `FROM <table-name>` is also needed.

Comment: Have 3 dogs instead of 2, with different ages, to make the problem clearer.

Comment: It is very long, hard and complex query with joins. I tried to extract only this piece of logic. CASE WHEN /THEN/ELSE  solved this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *both* strays and pets separately, then you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN d.owner IS NULL THEN 'stray' ELSE 'pet' END) as status,
       COUNT(*) as dogs_count, SUM(d.age) AS total_age
FROM dogs d
GROUP BY status;
```

You can also use conditional aggregation to put the values all in one row:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as dogs_count, SUM(d.age) AS total_age,
       SUM(d.owner IS NULL) as num_strays,
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.owner IS NULL THEN d.age ELSE 0 END) as strays_age
FROM dogs d
```

Comment: . . . `status` will always `stray`. So, `case` expression is really required ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma - surely dogs with owners aren't strays?

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select count(*) as Total_Dogs, sum(d.owner IS NOT NULL) as dogs_count, 
       sum(d.age) as total_age
from dog d;
```

Comment: Simply `sum(d.owner)` - why do you need an extra operation? `owner=0` hardly...